# Strange issue with ComboBox in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a few ComboBoxes, all with manually created items. In Designer.cs I've added `this.comboBoxName.SelectedIndex = 0;` so first item in collection is selected by default.

Now when I go to [Design] view and change `DropDownStyle` of **any** ComboBox - VS automatically deletes `this.comboBoxName.SelectedIndex = 0;` lines from **all** ComboBoxes.

I would understand if it happens with tho one being modified but why **all**?

**Edit**

System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Something else? There are various designers in VS, and various `ComboBox`es in the framework.

Comment: First you answer my question, I accept it and 5 mins later you want more details?

Comment: If you look at the data at the end of my comment, you'll see it was posted (currently) 20 minutes ago. If you look at the same on my answer, it was posted 15 minutes ago. I asked for more information and *then* realised that it was likely about editing inside the designer generated code, so I could answer. However, I don't think it's bad to leave the comment since, as a general rule, it would have been useful for you to specify the information I asked about.

Comment: Sorry I checked your post and comment times 3 times and I was sure I was right. I shouldn't write anything more, I'm totally dumb today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your putting your code inside an area that's auto-generated by the designer. You're not meant to do that.

That's why it has a notice at the top telling you not to do it. Something along the lines of:

```
/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
```

You need to put your code inside an appropriate event handler outside of the designer generated code.